# How Can I add onTap to image category

Tags: flutter

I want to add onTap to each category in my horizontal list view so how can I do it?

```
class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
        child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Category(
            image_location: "catogories/name.png",
            ),
          ],
      ),
    );
 }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your Category widget with [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) widget.

```
class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 80.0,
            child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                //This will be called on tap 
              },
              child:Category(
                image_location: "catogories/name.png",
              ),
            ),
            ],
          ),
        );
     }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **small sized images**, you can use `IconButton()`.

```
class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
        child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Image.asset(<name_here(or any other optoin such as Image.network()>)), onPressed: <function_here:fox example clickEvent()>)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also use

`icon: Icon(icon: Icons.<icon_name>, color: Colors.<colors_name>)`

, if you're using Icons.

**And if you're trying to do something else, comment below !**

Comment: class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,

      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: ()=> Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> firstClsAC())),
              child: Category(
                image_location: "catogories/1stclassobservation.png",
              )
          )
          ,